# Using esbuild for a custom bundler toolchain in Go-only

Tags: esbuild

I'm experimenting with esbuild in Go (no Node). I'm noticing that it wont resolve my imports automatically, which makes sense because there's no package manager.

Is there currently a way to resolve package dependencies in Go without npm? Perhaps a Skypack plugin written in Go or a local package cache utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example esbuild plugin on their website that lets you do HTTP-based resolving of import paths: https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#http-plugin

That's very, very handy.